# Why can't I add Geometry Nodes Modifier?

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes, geometry

I was fallowing a tutorial where a guy adds Geometry Nodes Modifier to a curve. Tried to do it but I can't. "New" button is inactive. It works only when I convert the curve to a mesh but it complicates a lot later on. Maybe there's an add-on I need to activate?

This is the tutorial: https://youtu.be/EbT2vvNNp00?t=143

[image]

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of your blender window? What Blender version do you use?

Comment: I use 2.93 version

Answer (score 1):

Geometry nodes modifier is supported on curves only in version 3.0 and above (https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/Nodes_Physics).

And Geometry nodes in 2.93 and 3.0 have a lot of differences, you will not be able to follow the tutorial using 2.93

Comment: Thank you very much!